# Cancel tests (with warning) from

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

My project has some unit tests. They all depend on some external service, over which I have no control. This service is frequently down (recall Twitter circa 2008). Currently, if the service is down, then the tests fail, and the continuous integration server won't build. I resent this. I'd like to ignore the tests that depend on this setup, printing a warning.

```
[BeforeScenario]

try
{
    connect(server)
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to connect to server {0}", server), x);
}
```

How can I do this? I happen to be using SpecFlow today, but I'd also like to know how to do this from NUnit.

Below is what I have currently. It's okay. The tests are ignored, but the build still fails.

```
[BeforeScenario]

try
{
    connect(server)
}
catch (Exception x)
{      
    throw new SpecFlowCancelTests(String.Format("Failed to connect to server {0}", server), x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either [Assert.Inconclusive("message")](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.1) or [Assert.Ignore()](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.1) utility methods:

> The Assert.Inconclusive method indicates that the test could not be
>   completed with the data available. It should be used in situations
>   where another run with different data might run to completion, with
>   either a success or failure outcome.
>
> The Assert.Ignore method provides you with the ability to dynamically
>   cause a test or suite to be ignored at runtime. It may be called in a
>   test, setup or fixture setup method. We recommend that you use this
>   only in isolated cases. The category facility is provided for more
>   extensive inclusion or exclusion of tests or you may elect to simply
>   divide tests run on different occasions into different assemblies.

Useful links:
 - [What is the Inconclusive Test Condition?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sachinre/archive/2006/07/29/what-is-the-inconclusive-test-condition_3f00_.aspx)